# Changing a property with generic key on React Class with Immer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, immer.js

I'm trying update the values of a form, utilizing the Component as a class, and trying to do less code, tried to use Immer for this.

## State Class

```
interface State {
 term: Term,
 ...
}
```

## Term Class

```
interface Term{
 firstname: string,
 surname: string,
 address: Address,
 ...
}
```

## Address Class

```
interface Address{
 zipcode: string,
 street: string,
 ...
}
```

The changes on Address are made by this handler

```
 handleAddressChange = (newValue:string, key:keyof Address) => {
      this.setState((prevVal) => {
        prevVal.term.address = produce<Address>(prevVal.term.address,(draft) => {
          draft[key] = newValue;
        })
      })
  }
```

In the `draft[key]...` line, i just receive the error 'Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'never' even typing the produce with .
How is possible to fix that?

**UPDATE**

```
this.setState(produce<State>(state =>{
      const newState: State = { ...state };
      newState.term.address = {...newState.term.address, [modelKey]: newValue}
      console.log(newState)
      return newState;
    }))
```

Worked for now, if you know another way type below.